# Boost library client-server application

Tags: c++, boost, server, client, boost-asio

I built simple boost application from boost documentation website but still don't know how to use it yet.

```
1- Server application:
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
    time_t now = time(0);
    return ctime(&now);
}

int main()
{
    try
    {
        boost::asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::acceptor acceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13));

        for (;;)
        {
            tcp::socket socket(io_service);
            acceptor.accept(socket);

            std::string message = make_daytime_string();

            boost::system::error_code ignored_error;
            boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(message), ignored_error);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

2- client application:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<exception>
#include "boost\array.hpp"
#include "boost\asio.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    try
    {
        if (argc != 2)
        {
            cerr << "usage: client <host>" << endl;
            return 1;
        }

        asio::io_service io_service;

        tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);

        tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");

        tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);

        tcp::socket socket(io_service);

        asio::connect(socket, endpoint_iterator);

        for (;;)
        {
            boost::array<char, 128> buf;
            system::error_code error_code;

            size_t len = socket.read_some(asio::buffer(buf), error_code);

            if (error_code == asio::error::eof)
                break; //Connection closed.
            else
                throw system::system_error(error_code);

            cout.write(buf.data(), len);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    while (true)
    {
    }

    return 0;
}
```

so, what next?

I exe then the client but dont see any more that flash console application.

(note: both application are compiled fine and no problem with the configuration.

Comment: If you like to see the console output add a `std::cin.get()` at the end of your `while` loop.

Comment: @Wum Huh, what? I'd rather open two terminals and run the server in one and the client in the other.

Comment: This server just sends the current date and time to the client after successful connection and then terminates it. The client _does not_ show the message and just exits. (see @DmitryBakhtiyarov's answer) There is not more to it.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, of course you could do this. But I expected him to run the apps in an IDE where the terminal per default closes automatically after the program having finished. As a quick help he could simply add `std::cin.get()` resulting in the terminal staying open until he pushes the any key.

Comment: @wum Running client/server stuff from the IDE is just silly. So what you want to discuss? And even if running from the IDE in debug mode, a breakpoint should suffice. No need for unnecessary `std::cin.get()`statements. Keep an eye of what you advise and why please

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ As I already said I meant a quick help - sentences like "dont see any more that flash console" make me feel the question poster is not very comfortable with coding in general. But I agree, of course a breakpoint suffices. Why do you think running client/server stuff from IDE is silly? How would you debug this?

Comment: am very comfortable with coding but not comfortable at all with this boost library (asio). documentation is very poor and not comprehensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 for (;;)
    {
        ...

        if (error_code == asio::error::eof)
            break; //Connection closed.
        else
            throw system::system_error(error_code);
        //code after this line will never be executed

        cout.write(buf.data(), len);
    }
```

Your client don't write any data in console - execution of loop will be breaked over throwing exception or break command

Comment: but no connection is happening otherwise no exception is thrown.